# Custom DHCP Server on home network

Tags: networking

I have a computer network at my house which consists of two computers and one server.
I have a software on dedicated server which requires direct connection to internet (port forwarding doesn't work for this).

So I plan to setup network in the following way:

[image: link text]

Please let me know if this will work. How good or bad could this be?

Internet Connection: Verizon Fios 25/25

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this would work fine. Another possibility would be to [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)) your server. This gives it full access as if it were a direct internet connection. You can forward certain ports to other computers if you would like, but the DMZ'd server is, for all effective purposes, directly on the internet. This may be a safer way to do it, especially since it would give you the ability to block specific ports if you don't want them all to be allowed.

Comment: Will this work without a router?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to set up a DHCP server, that will work fine.

What OS/platform is the server running?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running GNU or UNIX, you can install DHCPd software on your server. It is quite easy to configure. Just specify a subnet (for example: 192.168.100.0/24 (this will server 254 clients, beginning from 192.168.100.1 -> 192.168.100.254) and the rest takes care of itself. If it runs a firewall, be sure to allow UDP ports 67/68